# How to use OnCollisionStay on another gameObject in Unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first stack overflow question, but I'm doing a game jam, and I need to use the OnCollisionStay() void thing on the collider of another game object.
I have tried

```
public void TeleportDisplayCircle.OnCollisionStay(Collision2D tpPlatform)
```

but that didnt work. Do have any tips to help?
Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html

Comment: so, instead of using the gameobject `TeleportDisplayCircle` I should use its respective collider?

Comment: can you edit your question? because it is unclear, make it more clear to get the right answer

Comment: It is unclear what the `TeleportDisplayCircle` game object is. Use what is written in the docs

Comment: The script is running on a player GameObject, and the teleportDisplayCircle is displaying how for away the player can teleport. I want to find out of a platform is in this display circle using OncollisionStay(), but I dont know how to use that on the display circle's collider. THats the question

Comment: can you please share the document you are following for implementing this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do `public void TeleportDisplayCircle.OnCollisionStay(Collision2D tpPlatform)`

you have to `public void OnCollisionStay(Collision2D tpPlatform)` and this method has to be put into the script on some object you want to detect collision stay on

Comment: Yeah its impossible to call OnCollisionSomethings on other object. It has to be called on the objects where it is written.

Answer (score 0):

For next time, what you could do is on the object with the collider, create a script with your code in the `void OnCollisionStay()` then have this script reference your main script. Then you can create your own void on the main script `public void OnCollisionStaying(){}`. Then in your `OnCollisionStay()` on the collider you can say `mainscript.OnCollisionStaying();`